# Do I need to set ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );?

Tags: php, unicode

My framework for each pages does the follow:

```
ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
ini_set('mbstring.func_overload',7);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Do I need to do a `ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );` too?

Comment: http://php.net/default_charset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't have to.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

sets this for every page already

Comment: This does not cover everything. As @itpastorn and kzqai point out further down, there are PHP functions such has htmlentities (and others) that look at default_charset.

Comment: If you are using UTF-8 you and the default_charset directive in php.ini is set to some other encoding especially another multibyte encoding, then you're going to have problems even if you set internal_encoding to UTF-8 in php.ini. This is because certain functions like htmlentities and htmlspecialchars expect the default_charset unless otherwise specified. As stated in the above comment you need to set your default_charset to UTF-8 in php.ini.

Comment: You only get that if the `default_charset` is already set to `UTF-8`.  This does not answer the question, or even attempt to address the other nuances.

Answer (score 7):

Please see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29983 looks to me like some distros still have the problem

test case

```
echo "ini_get('default_charset') ". ini_get('default_charset')."<br>";

if (!ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')) {
echo "could not set default_charset to utf-8<br>";
}
```

Comment: This is... ...very worrying.  I'm running ubuntu 14.04 with php 5.5 and this still occurs...

Comment: Any distro or hosting provider can restrict what `php.ini` settings their clients can change.  It seems this was an actual mistake.  But if you use cheap shared hosting, you may encounter similar problems for many other settings, which you can't change without spending decades in queues to call-centres populated by clueless staff.

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to the http-header, you're OK as the other answers explain.

But: There are some functions that are default charset aware

From the description of [FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php):

> Like htmlspecialchars, this filter is aware of the default_charset and if a sequence of
>   bytes is detected that makes up an invalid character in the current
>   character set then the entire string is rejected resulting in a
>   0-length string.

Comment: Same with http://php.net/htmlentities and of course http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 3):

default_charset ini setting should work for you. PHP always outputs a character encoding by default in the Content-type: header using this setting

Comment: There's also the issue of how strings are handled internally by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should set UTF-8 as the default charset at the server configuration level.  If your hosting provider is setting another, then you would need to override it with an `.ini` setting, or choose another hosting provider.  Most set UTF-8 as the default now.

In 2023, you want to be using a universal character set that is capable of all languages, emojis, and whatnot.  The only other alternatives for that are UTF-16 and UTF-32, which are more wasteful bytewise for latin or cyrillic text.

The strings you handle in your PHP app may be encoded differently.  The `.ini` setting won't affect that.  You can use `mb_detect_encoding` and `mb_convert_encoding` if you may recieve text whose encoding is unknown.