# Issue while fetching data from database using web-services

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I have created web-service to get data from database which is in Gujarati(other language).

While i am accessing that URL of web-service in browser i am getting "????????????"  instead of real data.

Please help me to get out of it.

Thanks

Comment: depends on what encoding does the website use, and what encoding do you use in browser

Comment: bdia question rahul, I upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rahul bhai, try to run this script first:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}

$mysqli->close();
?
```

If you can modify the web-service, try to set charset to `utf-8` as shown above, or browse stackoverflow for similar questions, where users ask to set charset etc

Comment: Rahul bhai plz 'upvote'/'mark as answer' if this solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

you have to set encoding

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

on your webservice php file.

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); sets this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229696/do-i-need-to-set-ini-set-default-charset-utf-8

Comment: some times the set header does not match the one that you define http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-php