# Issue with PHP and UTF-8 Characters

Tags: php, utf-8

I've been working on a website recently (localhost environment).
Today I made it online and I encountred a really wierd problem :

When ever I try to output UTF-8 characters (hebrew) from my database it works perfectly, but when I try to echo simple text (ex: echo "שלום";) I get question marks (not the ones with the black background).

I've tried to search for a solution but found none. I hope you guys can help me with this

Comment: I ask it too often: What have you tried?

Comment: Have you checked that your meta data for your website is set to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

1. Did you try telling the client browser what character set you're using: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` ([<meta charset="utf-8"> vs <meta http-equiv="Content-Type">](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4696499/1481489))
2. Is your file/editor set for UTF-8? Eclipse defaults to cp1252, common windows editors will default to ISO-8859-1 or UCS-2.
3. In your php.ini file, confirm `default_charset = "UTF-8"` (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset)
4. Force the content type in the HTTP transaction (via response header): `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` Be sure to include this before any content is flushed to the browser.

Comment: 1. Yes, I have tried both of them but none work.
2. Also yes. I have checked it and its UTF-8, I use dreamweaver if it helps you somehow

Comment: @user2012389 what if you just put those characters in plain html... bypassing PHP?

Comment: if you have access to your php.ini: `default_charset = "UTF-8"` (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset)

Comment: What do I do if I don't have access to my PHP.ini?

Comment: @user2012389 I really think it is a problem with dreamweaver (http://hsmoore.com/how-to-save-a-dreamweaver-document-as-utf8/ - if this works, i'll update my answer accordingly). You can use ini_set or simply omit editing the php.ini and do #4 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229696/do-i-need-to-set-ini-set-default-charset-utf-8).

Comment: Okay, I now noticed a really wierd thing. My website has an Admin Panel I made (myweb.com/panel), and hebrew works perfectly there.. And I tried all the things you told me to try but again, none worked. I srsly dont understand this..

Answer (score 0):

Your encoding is wrong in your code files. Your editor saved them wrong, and you probably did not bother to also send a HTTP header for "Content-type", and your localhost also did not, but your online server now does.

Change the encoding, and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. Use this code to solve it:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```